# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given (loop)

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm looping for string overlaps between two arrays, deleting those values where there is one, so that only the empty values of $check remain, in this case $check[5].

The second one, $check, is multidimensional.

```
    $names = ["bob", "selena", "hailey", "rob", "justin", "robocop"];

    $check = [
        ["justin"], //bob
        ["justin", "selena", "robocop"],  //selena
        ["justin"], //hailey
        ["justin", "rob"], //rob
        [], //justin
        ["justin", "selena", "bob"] //robocop
    ];


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {

        for ($j = 0; $j < count($check); $j++) {

            if (in_array($names[$i], $check[$j])) {

                unset($check[$j]);

            }


        }


    }
```

The first loop runs through $names, the second through $check.

If the current string from $names (`$names[i]`)
is present in the current array of `$check ($check[j])`
the array is removed.

However, the console prints a warning: `in_array()` expects parameter 2 to be array, null given. I find this strange, because `$check[j]` should be equal to one of the arrays inside of $check.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few iterations of the outer loop, you will have unset most of `$check`. With a `for` loop like that, you're counting on specific numeric keys being there, but since you unset them, their values are undefined, a.k.a. `null`.

You can avoid this by using foreach loops instead.

```
foreach ($names as $name) {

    foreach ($check as $key => $array) {

        if (in_array($name, $array)) {

            unset($check[$key]);

        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are keep on unsetting the $check array, the size of the $check array will go down. Hence the $check won't return a value for the higher values of $j

You can do a minor modification in this code segment as follows

```
    $checkcount = count($check);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {

    for ($j = 0; $j < $checkcount; $j++) {

        if (isset($check[$j]) && in_array($names[$i], $check[$j])) {

            unset($check[$j]);


        }


    }
```